# How to update rows in SQLiteDB(android) inside a cursor adapter on button click, using content uri?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-adapter, android-cursoradapter

Ok this is annoying but I've been at it for long now. 
The button is not updating the values

This is the cursor adapter class, I know it's a lot of code, but you need to look only at the bind view after I have declared the button. I gave the entire code in case it helps someone else implement other things -

`public class FruitsFragmentCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

```
public FruitsFragmentCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    super(context,cursor,0);

}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.fragment_fruits,parent,false);
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view,  final Context context, final Cursor cursor) {

    //final

    //First find all the views that I want to modify individually
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.fruit_fragment_fruit_image);
    TextView engTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.fruit_fragment_english_name);
    TextView hindiTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.fruit_fragment_hindi_name);
    TextView measureTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.fruit_fragment_unit_measure);
    TextView priceTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.fruit_fragment_unit_price);
    final TextView quantityTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.fruit_fragment_quantity_text_view);
    TextView priceCalTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.fruit_fragment_price_calculation);

    //Find the columns of the attributes we are interested in
    int columnImage = cursor.getColumnIndex(itemsSoldContractEntry.COLUMN_IMAGE);
    int columnEngName = cursor.getColumnIndex(itemsSoldContractEntry.COLUMN_ITEM_NAME_ENGLISH);
    int columnHinName = cursor.getColumnIndex(itemsSoldContractEntry.COLUMN_ITEM_NAME_HINDI);
    int columnMeasure = cursor.getColumnIndex(itemsSoldContractEntry.COLUMN_MEASURE);
    int columnPrice = cursor.getColumnIndex(itemsSoldContractEntry.COLUMN_UNIT_PRICE);
    final int columnQuantity = cursor.getColumnIndex(itemsSoldContractEntry.COLUMN_QUANTITY);
    final int columnItemSoldID = cursor.getColumnIndex(itemsSoldContractEntry.COLUMN_ITEM_ID);
    final int columnID = cursor.getColumnIndex(itemsSoldContractEntry._ID);

    //Read the attributes from the cursor
    final String image = cursor.getString(columnImage);
    final String engName = cursor.getString(columnEngName);
    String hinName = cursor.getString(columnHinName);
    String measure = cursor.getString(columnMeasure);
    String price = cursor.getString(columnPrice);
    String quantity = cursor.getString(columnQuantity);

    //get the string for the cal text view separately
    String calculation = quantity + " x "+price + " = " + Integer.parseInt(quantity)*Integer.parseInt(price);

    //Decode the string to create a bitmap
    byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(image,Base64.DEFAULT);
    Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString,0,decodedString.length);

    //Update the text views with the values
    imageView.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);
    engTextView.setText(engName);
    hindiTextView.setText(hinName);
    measureTextView.setText("per "+measure);
    priceTextView.setText("₹ " + price);
    quantityTextView.setText(quantity);
    priceCalTextView.setText(calculation);

    //Define the two buttons (increment and decrement)
    Button incrementsButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.fruit_fragment_increment);

    //Get the position of the cursor
    final int position = cursor.getPosition();

    //Set the onclick listener
    incrementsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //Set up a content values object to hold the quantity when updated
            ContentValues incrementValue = new ContentValues();

            //Move the cursor to the position of the current item under operation
            cursor.moveToPosition(position);
            //Update the quantity value
            int oldQuantity = (cursor.getInt(columnQuantity));
            int newQuantity = oldQuantity +1;
            //Works till here
            //Put the value in the content values
            incrementValue.put(itemsSoldContractEntry.COLUMN_QUANTITY,newQuantity);
            //Selection claus which will point to the item_sold_id which will be updated
            String selection = itemsSoldContractEntry._ID + "=?";
            //Get the item id which should be updated
            int item_id = cursor.getInt(columnID);
            String itemIDArgs = Integer.toString(item_id);
            //Works till here

            //Selection args claus
            String[] selectionArgs = {itemIDArgs};
            //Update the value
            int something = context.getContentResolver().update(itemsSoldContractEntry.CONTENT_URI_ITEMS_SOLD,incrementValue,selection,selectionArgs);
            Log.v("Updated"," Row"+ something);


            //This is a toast to check if the correct item is being clicked
            Toast.makeText(context,something+"",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            //New quantity
            String newQu = cursor.getString(columnQuantity);

            quantityTextView.setText(newQu);



        }
    });
}
```

}

Everytime I click on the button, it doesn't update. I don't know why. I have gone through all docs of google and scoured stackoverflow. Still no clue. It returns 0 all the time. 
In the comments I have added till what part it works. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. If you notice I use a URI to access the database. I realized the URI was not configured to handle the update and hence was returning 0(the number of rows updated). Once that was fixed it was pretty simple. 
Attaching the code with the fix -

```
 //Move the cursor to the position of the current item under operation
            cursor.moveToPosition(position);
            //Update the quantity value
            int oldQuantity = (cursor.getInt(columnQuantity));
            int newQuantity = oldQuantity +1;
            //Works till here
            //Put the value in the content values
            incrementValue.put(itemsSoldContractEntry.COLUMN_QUANTITY,newQuantity);
            //Selection claus which will point to the item_sold_id which will be updated
            String selection = itemsSoldContractEntry._ID + "=?";
            //Get the item id which should be updated
            int item_id = cursor.getInt(columnID);
            String itemIDArgs = Integer.toString(item_id);
            //This is a toast to check if the correct item is being clicked
            Toast.makeText(context,itemIDArgs+"",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //Works till here

            //Selection args claus
            String[] selectionArgs = {itemIDArgs};
            //Update the value

            int something = context.getContentResolver().update(
                    Uri.withAppendedPath(itemsSoldContractEntry.CONTENT_URI_ITEMS_SOLD,Integer.toString(item_id)),
                    incrementValue,
                    selection,selectionArgs);
```

Note - My content provider has a functionality of just writing to one row instead of the entire table and hence if you notice I have appended the id at the end of the URI in the code where I update the quantity.